# robots.txt which folders to disallow - SEO?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, googlebot

I am currently writing my robots.txt file and have some trouble deciding whether I should allow or disallow some folders for SEO purposes.

Here are the folders I have:

- /css/ (css)
- /js/ (javascript)
- /img/ (images i use for the website)
- /php/ (PHP which will return a blank page such as for example checkemail.php which checks an email address or register.php which puts data into a SQL database and sends an email)
- /error/ (my error 401,403,404,406,500 html pages)
- /include/ (header.html and footer.html I include)

I was thinking about disallowing only the PHP pages and let the rest.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

/css and /js -- CSS and Javascript files will probably be crawled by googlebot whether or not you have them in robots.txt.  Google uses them to render your pages for site preview.  Google has asked nicely that you **not** put them in robots.txt.

/img -- Googlebot may crawl this even when in robots.txt the same way as CSS and Javascript.  Putting your images in robots.txt generally prevents them from being indexed in Google image search.  Google image search may be a source of visitors to your site so you may wish to be indexed there.

/php -- sounds like you don't want spiders hitting the urls that perform actions.  Good call to use robots.txt

/error -- If your site is set up correctly the spiders will probably never know what directory your error pages are served from.  They generally get served at the url that has the error and the spider never sees their actual url.  This isn't the case if you redirect to them, which isn't recommended practice anyway.  As such, I would say there is no need to put them in robots.txt

Comment: I forgot to ask... What should i do with my foder /include/ I guess I should also disallow it in robots.txt right ?

Comment: php files that are not meant to be executed standalone?  I'd actually try to move them out of webserver directory.  I usually "include ../file.php" for this.  But if you can't do that, robots.txt for sure.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Redirecting to error pages is one way that I have used to avoid crawlers to find specific URLs that perform actions (controllers) that are only supposed to be accessed in particular cases (either related to logged in users or links generated for specific users). I don't want spiders to be targeting those, I cannot move them out of the webserver directory, they're too many to be listed in robots.txt and I don't want people to find them out. So I just placed the /error pages in the robots.txt like Laurent did. I know this is from 2013, but what do you recommend now?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend redirecting to error pages.    Instead you should use appropriate error codes without redirection.   Returning 403 forbidden response rather than a redirect would be ideal.   If you are redirecting to error pages, listing those error pages in robots.txt is absolutely fine.